# Log4j2 and Spring 4

Tags: spring, slf4j, log4j2

I'm not able to make Log4j2 write Spring and Spring Security log messages (the latter I absolutely need [to solve an issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42159668/spring-security-user-auth-sometimes-fails-and-user-is-redirected-to-login-page)) on log file. I've read a lot here and elsewhere (like in the [Spring reference](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#overview-logging), of course) but I cannot make the solutions I found work for my case.

It's important to note that on both the solutions below, **mine logging messages and hibernate ones are written correctly on file. The problem affects only Spring messages.**

As far as I understand, Spring uses jcl (commons-logging) and there are two ways to let Spring uses Log4j2:

- simply adding the bridge **log4j-jcl** (jcl -> log4j2)
- using SLF4J with **jcl-over-jcl** and **log4j-slf4j-impl** (jcl -> slf4j -> log4j2)

I tried to exclude commons-logging from every other dependecy, in order to control manually its inclusion. In the first solution I let it included, in the second I exclude it, but I've seen diverse opinions on the topic. Anyway, in both cases Spring doesn't log.

I can see that hibernate uses **jboss-logging**. Is this the reason why it works on both configuration? Can its inclusion be a problem for Spring logging?

Can the application server be a problem on this? Maybe some library loaded by default that overrides application libs making a mess?

This is my environment:

- Java 1.6
- Servlet 2.5
- Oracle weblogic 12.1
- Spring MVC 4.3.4.RELEASE
- Spring Security 4.2.0.RELEASE
- Log4j 2.3 (last version compatible with Java 6)
- Hibernate entity manager 4.2.21.final
- SLF4J 1.7.22

I guess there is a dependency problem: some library that shouldn't be there or that is missing.

**EDIT:**
From my dependency tree I don't see a dependency of `spring-core` on `commons-logging`, like reference says. I can see one of `spring-data-jpa` on `slf4j` and on `jcl-over-slf4j`. The presence of `jcl-over-sl4j` shluld be the problem, as rgoers suggested. I'll update results...

So this is my **pom.xml** dependencies section (as you can see there are two different logging dependencies configuration, one commented; both this configuration make mine and hibernate logs working good, but neither of the two makes Spring ones written):

```
<properties>
    <spring.version>4.3.4.RELEASE</spring.version>
    <spring.security.version>4.2.0.RELEASE</spring.security.version>
    <!--<spring.data.jpa.version>1.10.5.RELEASE</spring.data.jpa.version>-->
    <spring.data.jpa.version>1.7.2.RELEASE</spring.data.jpa.version>
    <thymeleaf.version>3.0.2.RELEASE</thymeleaf.version>
    <log4j.version>2.3</log4j.version>
    <hibernate.validator.version>5.3.2.Final</hibernate.validator.version>
    <hibernate.entitymanager.version>4.2.21.Final</hibernate.entitymanager.version> <!-- LAST VERSION SUPPORTING JPA 2.0 (JPA 2.1 is not supported by WebLogic 12.1.1) -->
    <javax.transaction.version>1.1</javax.transaction.version>
    <oracle.jdbc.version>12.1.0.2</oracle.jdbc.version>
    <querydsl.jpa.version>3.6.9</querydsl.jpa.version>
    <google.guava.version>18.0</google.guava.version>
    <quartz.version>2.2.1</quartz.version>
    <pdfbox.version>2.0.4</pdfbox.version>

</properties>

<dependencies>

    <!-- SPRING SECURITY -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- WEB AND VALIDATION -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate.validator.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- THYMELEAF -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
        <artifactId>thymeleaf</artifactId>
        <version>${thymeleaf.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
        <artifactId>thymeleaf-spring4</artifactId>
        <version>${thymeleaf.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.mxab.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
        <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-data-attribute</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- LOGGING -->

    <!-- Using JCL -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>${log4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
        <version>${log4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-web</artifactId>
        <version>${log4j.version}</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-jcl</artifactId>
        <version>${log4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Using SLF4J -->
    <!--
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.22</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.22</version>
    </dependency>
    &lt;!&ndash;<dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.1</version>
    </dependency>&ndash;&gt;

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-slf4j-impl</artifactId>
        <version>${log4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>${log4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
        <version>${log4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    &lt;!&ndash;<dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-jcl</artifactId>
        <version>${log4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>&ndash;&gt;
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-web</artifactId>
        <version>${log4j.version}</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    -->

    <!-- PERSISTENCE LIBRARIES -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate.entitymanager.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
        <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
        <version>${javax.transaction.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- SPRING FRAMEWORK COMPONENTS -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.data.jpa.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- ORACLE JDBC -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle.jdbc</groupId>
        <artifactId>ojdbc7</artifactId>
        <version>${oracle.jdbc.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-configuration</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-configuration</artifactId>
        <version>1.10</version>
        <!--<exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>-->
    </dependency>

    <!-- SPRING-DATA JPA DATATABLES -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.darrachequesne</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-jpa-datatables</artifactId>
        <version>3.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- QUERYDSL -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mysema.querydsl</groupId>
        <artifactId>querydsl-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>${querydsl.jpa.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- GOOGLE GUAVA UTILS -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        <version>${google.guava.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- APACHE PDF BOX -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>
        <artifactId>pdfbox</artifactId>
        <version>${pdfbox.version}</version>
        <!--<exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>-->
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>
        <artifactId>fontbox</artifactId>
        <version>${pdfbox.version}</version>
        <!--<exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>-->
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>
        <artifactId>pdfbox-tools</artifactId>
        <version>${pdfbox.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-csv</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- ESAPI security features (prevent sql injection during password change -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.owasp.esapi</groupId>
        <artifactId>esapi</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.0.1</version>
        <exclusions>
            <!--<exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>-->
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>log4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.quartz-scheduler</groupId>
        <artifactId>quartz</artifactId>
        <version>${quartz.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.quartz-scheduler</groupId>
        <artifactId>quartz-jobs</artifactId>
        <version>${quartz.version}</version>
    </dependency>


</dependencies>
```

And this is my **log4j2 configuration**. But I really don't think that the problem is here.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="warn">

<Properties>
    <Property name="basePath">..\\logs\\myapp\\</Property>
</Properties>

<Appenders>
    <RollingFile name="fileLogger" fileName="${basePath}myapp.log" filePattern="${basePath}myapp-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log">
        <PatternLayout>
            <pattern>[%-5level] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} %c{10} - %msg%n</pattern>
        </PatternLayout>
        <Policies>
            <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy interval="1" modulate="true" />
        </Policies>
    </RollingFile>

    <Console name="console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
        <PatternLayout   pattern="[%-5level] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} %c{10} - %msg%n" />
    </Console>
</Appenders>

<Loggers>
    <Logger name="com.myapp" level="debug" additivity="true">
        <appender-ref ref="fileLogger" level="debug" />
    </Logger>
    <Logger name="org.springframework" level="info" additivity="true">
        <appender-ref ref="fileLogger" level="info" />
    </Logger>
    <!--<Logger name="org.springframework.security" level="debug" additivity="true">
        <appender-ref ref="fileLogger" level="debug" />
    </Logger>-->
    <Logger name="org.thymeleaf" level="info" additivity="true">
        <appender-ref ref="fileLogger" level="info" />
    </Logger>

    <Logger name="org.hibernate" level="debug" additivity="true">
        <appender-ref ref="fileLogger" level="debug" />
    </Logger>

    <Root level="info" additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="console" />
    </Root>
</Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

And the following are the libraries on my war, maybe something is in the way.

```
antisamy-1.5.3.jar
antlr-2.7.7.jar
aopalliance-1.0.jar
aspectjrt-1.8.4.jar
attoparser-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar
batik-css-1.8.jar
batik-ext-1.8.jar
batik-util-1.8.jar
bridge-method-annotation-1.13.jar
bsh-core-2.0b4.jar
c3p0-0.9.1.1.jar
classmate-1.3.1.jar
codegen-0.6.8.jar
commons-beanutils-core-1.8.3.jar
commons-codec-1.2.jar
commons-collections-3.2.2.jar
commons-configuration-1.10.jar
commons-csv-1.1.jar
commons-fileupload-1.3.1.jar
commons-httpclient-3.1.jar
commons-io-1.3.2.jar
commons-lang-2.6.jar
commons-logging-1.2.jar
dom4j-1.6.1.jar
ecj-4.3.1.jar
esapi-2.1.0.1.jar
fontbox-2.0.4.jar
guava-18.0.jar
hibernate-commons-annotations-4.0.2.Final.jar
hibernate-core-4.2.21.Final.jar
hibernate-entitymanager-4.2.21.Final.jar
hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.1.Final.jar
hibernate-validator-5.3.2.Final.jar
jackson-annotations-2.6.0.jar
jackson-core-2.6.6.jar
jackson-databind-2.6.6.jar
javassist-3.18.1-GA.jar
javax.el-api-2.2.5.jar
javax.inject-1.jar
jboss-logging-3.3.0.Final.jar
jboss-transaction-api_1.1_spec-1.0.1.Final.jar
jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.10.jar
jsr305-1.3.9.jar
jta-1.1.jar
log4j-api-2.3.jar
log4j-core-2.3.jar
log4j-jcl-2.3.jar
log4j-web-2.3.jar
mysema-commons-lang-0.2.4.jar
nekohtml-1.9.16.jar
ognl-3.1.10.jar
ojdbc7-12.1.0.2.jar
pdfbox-2.0.4.jar
pdfbox-debugger-2.0.4.jar
pdfbox-tools-2.0.4.jar
quartz-2.2.1.jar
quartz-jobs-2.2.1.jar
querydsl-apt-3.6.9.jar
querydsl-codegen-3.6.9.jar
querydsl-core-3.6.9.jar
querydsl-jpa-3.6.9.jar
slf4j-api-1.6.6.jar
spring-aop-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar
spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar
spring-context-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar
spring-core-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar
spring-data-commons-1.9.2.RELEASE.jar
spring-data-jpa-1.7.2.RELEASE.jar
spring-data-jpa-datatables-3.0.jar
spring-expression-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar
spring-jdbc-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar
spring-orm-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar
spring-security-config-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar
spring-security-core-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar
spring-security-web-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar
spring-tx-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar
spring-web-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar
spring-webmvc-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar
thymeleaf-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar
thymeleaf-extras-data-attribute-2.0.1.jar
thymeleaf-spring4-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar
unbescape-1.1.4.RELEASE.jar
validation-api-1.1.0.Final.jar
xalan-2.7.0.jar
xercesImpl-2.8.0.jar
xml-apis-1.3.03.jar
xml-apis-ext-1.3.04.jar
xom-1.2.5.jar
```

Every suggestion is appreciated.

Thank you all,
dolfiz

Comment: Probably not related to your problem, but you have 2 different pdfbox versions. At this time, the correct one is 2.0.4.

Comment: Thank you, I will fix it. Anyhow it does not affect the problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have several Spring applications that log using Log4j 2. The recommended method, as you say is to leave the commons-logging jar in and use log4j-jcl to bridge it to Log4j 2. In that scenario the jcl-over-slf4j jar must not be present. In this case the logging calls will be commons-logging -> log4j-jcl -> log4j-api.

As you have said, the other way is to remove the commons-logging jar and replace it with jcl-over-slf4j. You would then need all the jars you have commented out. In this case the logging calls would be jcl-over-slf4j -> slf4j-api -> log4j-slf4j-impl -> log4j-api.

As you can see the second path is a bit longer.

BTW - Your log4j2 configuration is missing the wrapping `<configuration>`element.

Comment: Thank you rgoers, but isn't it what I am doing in my pom? I'm declaring an explicit, although unnecessary, dependency for `commons-logging` (I need also for other libraries, like esapi for example). Then for `log4j-api` and `log4j-core`, and finally for `log4j-web`. The last one needed, I think, because I am in a 2.5 servlet environment, and not 3.0, so I need to declare the `log4jServletFilter` in my web.xml.

Comment: You are right, the presence of `jcl-over-slf4j` must be the problem. I'll try to exclude it.

Answer (score 1):

https://www.slf4j.org/legacy.html[image: slf4j legacy]

As you can see, you need add `jcl-over-slf4j.jar` and exclude `commons-logging.jar` (both has identical file structure inside, check it) After that, include `slf4j-api.jar`, bridge `slf4j-log4j.jar` and actual logging implementation - `log4j.jar`

Check for `commons-logging.jar` in resulted war file, it shouldn't present.

Comment: In my pom.xml file you can see a similar try that I commented. I've just only used **log4j-slf4j-impl** as bridge in place of **slf4j-log4j12** that you suggest (that, as far as I know should be used with Log4j 1.2). Anyway I tried both and as usual mine and hibernate's logs work, but Spring ones don't.

Comment: Please check for `commons-logging.jar` in resulted war file, it shouldn't present. Usually it is somewhere deep  in dependency tree.

Comment: Already checked, forgot to mention. When I use slf4j I exclude all commons-logging dependencies and check effective pom, dependency tree and also the libs into the war.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure JCL is implemented by Log4j2, not by bridged to other logging frameworks, avoid dependencies like "org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j".

To enforce this (i.e. to fail-fast if wrong dependency is added to a project ever again) you can add a rule for the maven-enforcer-plugin:

```
    <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>enforce-banned-dependencies</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>enforce</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <rules>
                    <bannedDependencies>
                        <excludes>
                            <!-- Prohibit routing Apache Commons Logging API via SLF4J, use more direct route to Log4j2. -->
                            <exclude>org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j</exclude>
                            <!-- Prohibit routing "java.util.logging" API via SLF4J, use more direct route to Log4j2. -->
                            <exclude>org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j</exclude>
                            <!-- Prohibit routing log4j-1.2 via SLF4J, use more direct route to Log4j2. -->
                            <exclude>org.slf4j:log4j-over-slf4j</exclude>
                        </excludes>
                    </bannedDependencies>
                </rules>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

As rgoers correctly said in his reply, if we choose to use log4j-jcl bridge, we **MUST** exclude every dependency on `jcl-over-slf4j`. In my case it was brought in by `spring-data-jpa`. The following is my final pom with that exclusion. I can finally see spring and spring security logs.

The next step will be try to bring in correctly `slf4j`, in order to obtain logs also for spring-data-jpa and thymeleaf, for example.

Thanks again to rgoers who pointed out the solution.

```
<properties>
    <spring.version>4.3.4.RELEASE</spring.version>
    <spring.security.version>4.2.0.RELEASE</spring.security.version>
    <spring.data.jpa.version>1.7.2.RELEASE</spring.data.jpa.version>
    <thymeleaf.version>3.0.2.RELEASE</thymeleaf.version>
    <log4j.version>2.3</log4j.version>
    <hibernate.validator.version>5.3.2.Final</hibernate.validator.version>
    <hibernate.entitymanager.version>4.2.21.Final</hibernate.entitymanager.version> <!-- LAST VERSION SUPPORTING JPA 2.0 (JPA 2.1 is not supported by WebLogic 12.1.1) -->
    <javax.transaction.version>1.1</javax.transaction.version>
    <oracle.jdbc.version>12.1.0.2</oracle.jdbc.version>
    <querydsl.jpa.version>3.6.9</querydsl.jpa.version>
    <google.guava.version>18.0</google.guava.version>
    <quartz.version>2.2.1</quartz.version>
    <pdfbox.version>2.0.4</pdfbox.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>

    <!-- SPRING SECURITY -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- WEB AND VALIDATION -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate.validator.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- THYMELEAF -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
        <artifactId>thymeleaf</artifactId>
        <version>${thymeleaf.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
        <artifactId>thymeleaf-spring4</artifactId>
        <version>${thymeleaf.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.mxab.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
        <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-data-attribute</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- LOGGING -->

    <!-- Using JCL -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>${log4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
        <version>${log4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-web</artifactId>
        <version>${log4j.version}</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-jcl</artifactId>
        <version>${log4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Using SLF4J -->
    <!--
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.22</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.22</version>
    </dependency>
    &lt;!&ndash;<dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.1</version>
    </dependency>&ndash;&gt;

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-slf4j-impl</artifactId>
        <version>${log4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>${log4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
        <version>${log4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    &lt;!&ndash;<dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-jcl</artifactId>
        <version>${log4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>&ndash;&gt;
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-web</artifactId>
        <version>${log4j.version}</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    -->

    <!-- PERSISTENCE LIBRARIES -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate.entitymanager.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
        <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
        <version>${javax.transaction.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- SPRING FRAMEWORK COMPONENTS -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.data.jpa.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <!-- ORACLE JDBC -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle.jdbc</groupId>
        <artifactId>ojdbc7</artifactId>
        <version>${oracle.jdbc.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-configuration</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-configuration</artifactId>
        <version>1.10</version>
        <!--<exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>-->
    </dependency>

    <!-- SPRING-DATA JPA DATATABLES -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.darrachequesne</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-jpa-datatables</artifactId>
        <version>3.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- QUERYDSL -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mysema.querydsl</groupId>
        <artifactId>querydsl-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>${querydsl.jpa.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- GOOGLE GUAVA UTILS -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        <version>${google.guava.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- APACHE PDF BOX -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>
        <artifactId>pdfbox</artifactId>
        <version>${pdfbox.version}</version>
        <!--<exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>-->
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>
        <artifactId>fontbox</artifactId>
        <version>${pdfbox.version}</version>
        <!--<exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>-->
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>
        <artifactId>pdfbox-tools</artifactId>
        <version>${pdfbox.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-csv</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- ESAPI security features (prevent sql injection during password change -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.owasp.esapi</groupId>
        <artifactId>esapi</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.0.1</version>
        <exclusions>
            <!--<exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>-->
            <!--<exclusion>
                <groupId>log4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            </exclusion>-->
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.quartz-scheduler</groupId>
        <artifactId>quartz</artifactId>
        <version>${quartz.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.quartz-scheduler</groupId>
        <artifactId>quartz-jobs</artifactId>
        <version>${quartz.version}</version>
    </dependency>


</dependencies>
```